# how to add both sum() and avg()?

Tags: metrics, looker-studio

I want to have both sum and avg metrics in the same table but I get an error...

[image]

My goal is to get a table with avg and the total sum, like:

```
> agent    avg()   sum()
> 
> agent1   3.34    35000
> 
> agent2   5.91    850
```

...

But I get this error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I do it manually it works:

[image]

I added:

[image]

Why would it work manually and not when I use the automatic avg() from the dropdown...?!

Comment: Why are you asking a question in your Answer?

Comment: that's a rhetorical question. Perhaps I should remove it. I can't believe I have to manually insert the formula for it to work...